# Android Beginner: Enabling Buttons

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-intent

I am creating an app which has two navigation bars at the top: "previous" and "next". I am trying to make it so that the buttons become disabled on the 1st and last page respectively. I am not sure why this code doesn't work. The previous button becomes disabled but the "next" button does not become enabled(false).

here is my code:

```
previous =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_previous);
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_next);
            previous.setOnClickListener(this);
            next.setOnClickListener(this);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        heading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textNavigationHeading);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textNavigationText); 



        Bundle ext = getIntent().getExtras();
        this.list = ext.getInt("list");
        this.page = ext.getInt("page");

        if(list == 0){
            itemsHeading = campaignHeadings;
            MAX_PAGES = campaignHeadings.length;
        }

        if(list == 1){
            itemsHeading = specopsHeadings;
            MAX_PAGES = specopsHeadings.length;
        }

        setContent();       
    }

    private void setContent() {
        heading.setText(itemsHeading[page]);
        text.setText("Blah blah blah");     
        checkButtons(page);
    }

    private void checkButtons(int page) {
        if(page == 0)
            previous.setEnabled(false);
        if(page != MAX_PAGES)
            next.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void resetButtons(int page){
        previous.setEnabled(true);
        next.setEnabled(false);
        checkButtons(page);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button_next:
            page += 1;
            break;
        case R.id.button_previous:
            page -= 1;
            break;
        }
        setContent();
        resetButtons(page);

    }
```

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which enables and disables the buttons is the following:

```
private void checkButtons(int page) {
    if(page == 0)
        previous.setEnabled(false);
    if(page != MAX_PAGES)
        next.setEnabled(true);
}

private void resetButtons(int page) {
    previous.setEnabled(true);
    next.setEnabled(false);
    checkButtons(page);
}
```

You have two different methods, and you call sometimes one, and sometimes the other. Make it one single method, which would look like this:

```
private void enableOrDisableButtons(int page) {
    previous.setEnabled(page != 0);
    next.setEnabled(page != (MAX_PAGES - 1));
}
```

Also, note that `MAX_PAGES` is the length of your list, and indices go from `0` to `length - 1` inclusive. So the next button needs to be disabled when the page is `MAX_PAGES - 1`.